My application crashes because of getSerializableExtra
getSerialiazableExtra is deprecated thats why I tried new methos with clazz but I think it causes this can you help me? there are 3 pages code
its mainactivty

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var landmarkList: ArrayList<LandMark>
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        landmarkList = ArrayList<LandMark>()


        //Data
        val pisa = LandMark("Pisa", "Italy", R.drawable.pisa)
        val colosseum = LandMark("Colosseum", "Italy", R.drawable.kolezyum)
        val eiffel = LandMark("Eiffel", "France", R.drawable.eiffel)
        val londonBridge = LandMark("London Bridge", "UK", R.drawable.bridge)

        landmarkList.add(pisa)
        landmarkList.add(colosseum)
        landmarkList.add(eiffel)
        landmarkList.add(londonBridge)

        //Adapter : Layout && Data
        //Mapping
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, landmarkList.map { landMark -> landMark.name })
        binding.listView.adapter = adapter

        binding.listView.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
            val intent = Intent(this,DetailsActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("landmarkName",landmarkList.get(position).name)
            startActivity(intent)

        }


    }
}

its landmark class
package com.example.landmarkbookkotlin

import java.io.Serializable

class LandMark (val name:String,val country:String,val image:Int) :Serializable{


}

its detailsactivity
class DetailsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityDetailsBinding

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityDetailsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        val intent = intent
        //casting
        val selectedLandMark = intent.getSerializableExtra("landmark") as LandMark
        binding.LandMarkName.text = selectedLandMark.name
        binding.LandMarkCountry.text = selectedLandMark.country
        binding.imageView.setImageResource(selectedLandMark.image)


    }
}




it should show other activity when I click listwiew but it crassesMainactivity with listview

I think that intent.putExtra("landmarkName",landmarkList.get(position).name) should really be intent.putExtra("landmark",landmarkList.get(position)).

Yes As @Jay said it should be intent.putExtra("landmark",landmarkList.get(position)). because you want to send the model not only the name of the landmark for specific position. Moreover you should use same name while using intent.putExtra and intent.getSerializableExtra. So, either use "landmarkName" or "landmark" in both activities.

@Maelstrom always post logs while asking code related questions.
